# Doing spatial join in QGIS between land parcels and zoning map, how can land use with biggest overlap give its attribute to parcel?

Tags: qgis-3, intersection, spatial-join, land-use, parcel

The parcel might have some small overlaps (or intersections?) from other land uses if the alignment of vertices is not perfect, I want to make sure the land use covering the largest part of the parcel is the one taken into account by QGIS. Both layers will be polygons. Not sure if I should choose intersect or overlap in this case also.

Comment: You could convert the "to be joined" layer to centroids and then do the join - provided you have no shapes where the centroid is outside the actual polygon.

Comment: In QGIS 3.14, I'm seeing an option for 'Join attributes by location' called  'Join type', and one of the choices for that option is 'Take attributes of the feature with largest overlap only (one-to-one)'. Have you tried that?

Comment: I will try, thanks to both of you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end selecting "Take attributes of the feature with largest overlap only (one-to-one) with overlap" as a choice in "Join Type" in Vector/Data Management Tools/Join Attributes by Location works perfectly.

The centroid method would have worked with shapes where the centroid is inside the shape, if not using the pole of inaccessibility might be a safer method, but in my case with QGIS the first method is really the easiest.